# Get Date as string from Firebase convert to date and compare that date with current to find difference in minutes

Tags: ios, swift

I know this is a oddly specific. But I want to pull a string from my firebase database that has the value `18-11-2017 10:41 AM`, I want to convert this back to Date and then compare it with the current date to find how many total minutes it has been since that timestamp.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let date1s = dateFormatter.date(from: break1s) //USED TO CONVERT STRING BACK TO DATE

let elapsed = Date().timeIntervalSince(date1s)

print((Int(elapsed) % 3600) / 60) //CONVERT SECONDS TO MINUTES
```

So from the date stored in my firebase database (`18-11-2017 10:30 AM`) I want to find how many minutes from that timestamp to the current timestamp. Say the current timestamp was `18-11-2017 11:45 AM` it should return a value of 75 because it's been an hour and 15 minutes. Does anyone know how this can be done in Swift 3?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the date from firebase in String

```
let dateString = "18-11-2017 10:41 AM"
```

Simple extention to convert String to Date with your date format

```
extension String{
    var date : Date?{
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy h:mm a"
        return dateFormatter.date(from: self)
    }
}
```

Compare minutes from 2 dates

```
extension Date {
    func minutes(from date: Date) -> Int {
        return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute], from: date, to: self).minute ?? 0
    }
}
```

Compare your date with current date

```
if let date = dateString.date{
   let minutes = Date().minutes(from: date) 
}
```

Comment: You are amazing. This worked like a charm. Thank you :)